# Docker port is not working over https after setting up an SSL over ubuntu nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, amazon-ec2, lets-encrypt

I set up the Letsencrypt certificate directly to an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance running Nginx and a docker server using port 9998. The domain is set up on Route 53. Http is redirected to https.

So https://example.com is working fine but https://example.com:9998 gets ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR. If I use the IP address like http://10.10.10.10:9997 is working and checked the server using port 9998 okay.

The snapshot of the server on docker is:

```
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
999111000        img-server         "/bin/sh -c 'java -j…"   21 hours ago        Up 21 hours         0.0.0.0:9998->9998/tcp   hellowworld
```

It seems something is missing between Nginx and the server using port 9998. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where have you configured the ssl certificate ? Only Nginx?

The reason why you cannot visit https://example.com:9998 using ssl protocal is that that port provides http service rather than https.

I suggest not to publish 9998 of hellowworld and proxy all the traffic with nginx (if Nginx is also started with docker and in the same network).

Configure https in Nginx and the origin sever provides http.

This is a **sample** configuration https://github.com/newnius/scripts/blob/master/nginx/config/conf.d/https.conf

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.com;
    return      301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen      443;
    server_name example.com;

    access_log  logs/example.com/access.log  main;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/debug.log debug;

    ssl on;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass       http://apache:80;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header CLIENT-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
        proxy_pass  http://apache:80;
    }

    # Deny all attempts to access hidden files such as .htaccess, .htpasswd, .DS_Store(Mac).
    location ~ /\. {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: SSL is on Nginx not inside Docker. Confused over http://apache:80. Firstly, is that port 80 or 9998. Because the service is running on port 9998, so somewhere it has to tell Nginx - confused. Secondly, is it apache:80 or 9998 or nginx:80? As I know, Nginx is running.